# Django template - Get values from a dict

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm passing a dict to my templates:-

```
a = {
    1: {
        'a': 'abc',
        'b': 'def'
    },
    2: {
        'a': 'ghi',
        'b': 'jkl'
    },
    'order': [1,2] 
}
```

Now I need to get the values of those keys which are present in `order` list.

In normal python I would do things like:-

```
for id in a['order']:
    print a[id]['a']
```

What is its equivalent in django templates?

This is what I've tried. It aint working

```
{% for id in a.order %}
    {{a.id.a}}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: In my opinion your approach is very bad, because you are placing logic inside your template. Don't do that in the template, determine the values that should be displayed in the view function. But if you really want to do it in the template, then maybe you should go with this option: `{% for key, value in a .items %}`. It works like `items()` in normal python and splits the dictionary into a list of tuple pairs.

Comment: His values are  determined. Hi just want them in right order. How items will help?

Comment: As work around you can use `OrderedDict` from `collections`.

Comment: @Arnial No! The OP didn't say anything about the order. And even then, that should be better done in the view, not in the template. Determining which keys are present in the 'order' list should be better done in the view. It is a good practice to avoid logic in the templates.

Comment: I agree with @cezar that the ordering logic should happen in the view - unless there are good reasons to do it in the template.

Comment: @xyres it's syntax of [django template](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter04.html#context-variable-lookup), not python syntax.

Answer (score 4):

You have to create a simple [template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/custom-template-tags/) to get items from a dict by key name:

```
#my_templatetags.py
from django.template.defaulttags import register

@register.filter
def get_item_by_key(dict, key):
    return dict.get(key)
```

And do something like the following in your template:

```
{% load my_templatetags %}
<ul>
{% for idx in a.order %}
    {% with item=a|get_item_by_key:idx %}
    <li>
        {{ item.a }} - {{ item.b }}
    </li>
    {% endwith %}
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```